# Compare 2 different lists based on 2 columns

Tags: loops, google-apps-script, comparison

I am trying to compare 2 lists based on 2 different columns and get the difference.

```
const list1 = [[121,"7/2/2019"], [131,"7/22/2019"], [141, ]]
const list2 = [[121, ], [131, ], [141, ]]
```

In the above 2 lists, I am trying to compare list1 with list2 based on the 2 columns - col1 and col2. First columnn (col1) [121,131,141] will always be the same in both the lists.

For every unique column 1 (col1) [121,131,141] in list1, compare the corresponding element in list2 based on second column, and if it is different, I am trying to output it to a different list

```
Result = [[121,"7/2/2019"], [131,"7/22/2019"]
```

Another example is

```
const list1 = [[121,"7/2/2019"], [131,"7/22/2019"], [141, ]]
const list2 = []

Result = [[121,"7/2/2019"], [131,"7/22/2019"], [141, ]]
```

I tried with the below code but it does not yield my desired result

```
const obj1 = list1.reduce((o, e) => Object.assign(o, {[e]: true}), {});
const obj2 = list2.reduce((o, e) => Object.assign(o, {[e]: true}), {});
const list3 = list2.filter(e => !obj1[e]); 
const list4 = list2.concat(list1.filter(e => !obj2[e]));
```

Any leads/suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this to compare rows in `list1` to the rows in `list2` that appear at the same position in their respective arrays:

`const difference = list1.filter((row, index) => row[1] !== list2[index][1]);`

If the rows are not guaranteed to appear in the same position, try this:

```
  const list1 = [[121, "7/2/2019"], [131, "7/22/2019"], [141,]];
  const list2 = [[121,], [131,], [141,]];
  const difference = list1.filter((row1, index) => {
    const list2row = list2.filter(row2 => row2[0] === row1[0])[0];
    return !Array.isArray(list2row) || row1[1] !== list2row[1];
  });
```

Comment: Thanks, but I get the error "TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined"

Answer (score 1):

As other pattern, for example, how about using `Map` as follows?

#### Sample script:

```js
const sample = (list1, list2) => {
  const m = new Map(list2);
  return list1.filter(([a, b]) => !m.has(a) || m.get(a) != b);
}

// Sample pattern 1.
const list1 = [[121, "7/2/2019"], [131, "7/22/2019"], [141,]];
const list2 = [[121,], [131,], [141,]];
const res1 = sample(list1, list2);

// Sample pattern 2.
const list3 = [];
const res2 = sample(list1, list3);

console.log(res1)
console.log(res2)
```

#### Note:

- In above sample script, 2nd element of `[141,]` is `undefined`. By this, the output value of this becomes `[141]`. If you want to output this value as the length of 2, how about modifying above script as follows?

  - From

    ```
      return list1.filter(([a, b]) => !m.has(a) || m.get(a) != b);
    ```
  - To

    ```
      return [...new Map(list1)].filter(([a, b]) => !m.has(a) || m.get(a) != b);
    ```
- You can test this with the following script.

```js
const sample = (list1, list2) => {
  const m = new Map(list2);
  return [...new Map(list1)].filter(([a, b]) => !m.has(a) || m.get(a) != b);
}

// Sample pattern 1.
const list1 = [[121, "7/2/2019"], [131, "7/22/2019"], [141,]];
const list2 = [[121,], [131,], [141,]];
const res1 = sample(list1, list2);

// Sample pattern 2.
const list3 = [];
const res2 = sample(list1, list3);

console.log(res1)
console.log(res2)
```

#### References:

- [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map)
- [filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

### Added:

From your following replying,

> If i read the dates from the google sheets, my lists are list1 = [[FH121, Fri Jul 12 00:00:00 GMT-04:00 2019], [FH131, Fri Jul 12 00:00:00 GMT-04:00 2019], [FH141, ]] and list2 = [[FH121, Fri Jul 12 00:00:00 GMT-04:00 2019], [FH131, Fri Jul 12 00:00:00 GMT-04:00 2019], [FH141, Wed Jul 10 00:00:00 GMT-04:00 2019]]. Sample function does not work as it returns all elements in list1 rather than just outputting one element which is [FH141, Wed Jul 10 00:00:00 GMT-04:00 2019]

I couldn't notice that the value of 2nd element in your samples was the date object. This is due to my poor skill. From your replying, I modified above script as follows.

#### Modified script:

```js
const list1 = [["FH121", new Date("2019-07-12 00:00:00")], ["FH131", new Date("2019-07-12 00:00:00")], ["FH141", ]];
const list2 = [["FH121", new Date("2019-07-12 00:00:00")], ["FH131", new Date("2019-07-12 00:00:00")], ["FH141", new Date("2019-07-10 00:00:00")]];

const m = new Map(list1);
const r = list2.filter(([a, b]) => !m.has(a) || (m.get(a) && m.get(a).getTime()) != (b && b.getTime()));
console.log(r);
```

Comment: If i read the dates from the google sheets, my lists are list1 = [[FH121, Fri Jul 12 00:00:00 GMT-04:00 2019], [FH131, Fri Jul 12 00:00:00 GMT-04:00 2019], [FH141, ]] and list2 = [[FH121, Fri Jul 12 00:00:00 GMT-04:00 2019], [FH131, Fri Jul 12 00:00:00 GMT-04:00 2019], [FH141, Wed Jul 10 00:00:00 GMT-04:00 2019]]. Sample function does not work as it returns all elements in list1 rather than just outputting one element which is  [FH141, Wed Jul 10 00:00:00 GMT-04:00 2019]

Comment: @user3447653 Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience. From your replying, I added one more sample script as an answer. Could you please confirm it? If that was not the direction you expect, I apologize again.

Comment: @user3447653 Did my answer show you the result what you want? Would you please tell me about it? That is also useful for me to study. If you have issues for my answer yet, I apologize. At that time, can I ask you about your current situation? I would like to study to solve your issues.

Answer (score 1):

If col(1) contains only unique values you can convert the data into an object where col(1) has keys and col(2) has values:

```js
const list1 = [[121,"7/2/2019"], [131,"7/22/2019"], [141, ]];
const list2 = [[121, ], [131, ], [141, ]];

const obj1 = Object.fromEntries(list1);
const obj2 = Object.fromEntries(list2);

var res = [];
for (prop in obj1) {
    if (obj2.hasOwnProperty(prop) && obj2[prop] != obj1[prop]) {
        res.push([prop, obj1[prop]]);
    }
}

console.log(res)
```

Your another example needs nothing but one line:

```
if (list2.length == 0) var res = list1;
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. If i read the dates from the google sheets, my lists are list1 = [[FH121, Fri Jul 12 00:00:00 GMT-04:00 2019], [FH131, Fri Jul 12 00:00:00 GMT-04:00 2019], [FH141, ]] and list2 = [[FH121, Fri Jul 12 00:00:00 GMT-04:00 2019], [FH131, Fri Jul 12 00:00:00 GMT-04:00 2019], [FH141, Wed Jul 10 00:00:00 GMT-04:00 2019]]. Sample function does not work as it returns all elements in list1 rather than just outputting one element which is  [FH141, Wed Jul 10 00:00:00 GMT-04:00 2019]

Comment: I'm not sure if I got you right. I tested my snippet with your data (list1 and list2) and it returns `[ [ 'FH141', undefined ] ]`. It makes sense if you want take data from list1 as a base for the result list. If you want take data from list2 as a base, you can change one line in my snipped: from `res.push([prop, obj1[prop]]);` to `res.push([prop, obj2[prop]]);` After that you will get `[ [ 'FH141', 'Wed Jul 10 00:00:00 GMT-04:00 2019' ] ]`

Comment: Or you want get data from list1 if the cell in list2 is empty or from list2 if the cell in list1 is empty? It can be done pretty easy as well. But from where the script should take data if both cell in list1 and list2 are non empty and contain different data?